# Проверьте пожалуйста - это причастный оборот?

Tags: синтаксис

*Бывало, маленькой девочкой, прищемив палец дверью, она сразу же в страхе оборачивалась к взрослому, **оказавшемуся ближе других**, и плакала у него на руках.*

Можно сказать, что это обособленный причастный оборот в функции атрибутивного определения?

Спасибо!

Comment: _Бывало маленькой девочкой..._ === По-моему, после "бывало" нужна запятая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, вы совершенно верно мыслите. Это действительно причастный оборот (в синтаксисе называемый обособленным определением, выраженным причастным оборотом).